# Building truth tables from dataframe with odd positions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a number of string variables.

```
library(tidyverse)

animals <- data.frame(
     a = c("antilope", "giraffe", "zebra"),
     b = c("giraffe", "zebra", NA),
     c = c("zebra", NA, NA))
```

I want to turn this into a table that displays a TRUE/FALSE if the animal is present anywhere in the row. I want the colnames to represent the animal type.

```
unique_names <- c("antilope", "giraffe", "zebra")

colnames(animals) <- unique_names
```

Hence my thought is to have R do a rowwise scan, and write TRUE if any one of the cells in the particular row match the column name. The end result should be:

```
data.frame(
  antilope = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
  giraffe = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
  zebra = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
)
```

I have managed to do this with a single pattern, like so:

```
animals %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  transmute(giraffe = any(str_detect(string= across(), pattern = "giraffe")))
```

I could repeat this line by copy/paste, but this doesn't seem like a very programmatic approach. Is it possible to do this in a more general manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Base R:

```
t(table(stack(animals)))>0
   values
ind antilope giraffe zebra
  a     TRUE    TRUE  TRUE
  b    FALSE    TRUE  TRUE
  c    FALSE   FALSE  TRUE
```

if you want a dataframe:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(stack(animals)))>0)

  antilope giraffe zebra
a     TRUE    TRUE  TRUE
b    FALSE    TRUE  TRUE
c    FALSE   FALSE  TRUE
```

If you need to use the `unique_name` vector: Note that you get a matrix, you can convert to dataframe

```
Vectorize(grepl, 'pattern')(unique_names, animals)
     antilope giraffe zebra
[1,]     TRUE    TRUE  TRUE
[2,]    FALSE    TRUE  TRUE
[3,]    FALSE   FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Those are some great suggestions. Thank you!